# What's the difference between location /foo and location ^~ /foo

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to understand the meaning of `^~` modifier in the location directive.

The docs says

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then
>   regular expressions are not checked.

But I can hardly wrap my head around it. Since it's a string prefix match, and is already matched, how are regular expressions still relevant here? What regular expressions is the doc referring to?

What's the different between

```
location /foo {}
location ^~ /foo {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expressions refer to :

- **~** modifier which means the location will be interpreted as a case-sensitive regular expression match.
- **~*** which means the location block will be interpreted as a case-insensitive regular expression match.

For example, in the following configuration:

```
location ~* \.(txt)$ {
     return 200 "in #1/\n";
}
location /foo1    {
     return 200 "in #2/\n";
}
location ^~ /foo2 {
     return 200 "in #3/\n";
}
```

So for the following URLs :

- **/foo1/bar/sample.txt** will return **in #1**
- **/foo2/bar/sample.txt** will return **in #3** since the longest matching prefix location has the **^~** modifier